# Check if string is number

Tags: string, vbscript, numbers

I am looking for a way to check if string is number.

For example:

- "12" is 12.
- "012" is 12.
- "0012" is 12.
- "f12" not int.

I try to use with `IsNumeric(x)` funtion, but for the example "012" it returns me false.

Does someone have an idea?

Comment: `print("012".isnumeric())` prints `true`, meaning that Python thinks its numeric.  So, I don't see where your problem is.  Even `int("012")` works properly.

Comment: `MsgBox IsNumeric("012")` as .vbs returns True for me.

Comment: Thanks from some reason now isnumeric("012") work!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `IsNumeric(x)` or use `RegExp` objects.

```
Number="12\"
WSH.Echo IsNumeric(Number) : ' Code = 0

Number=12
With New RegExp
 .Pattern = "^\d+$"
 .IgnoreCase = True
 .Global = True
 Set Matches = .Execute(Number)
End With
WSH.Echo Matches.Count : ' Code = 1
'Code 1 = Number
```